# Regex to allow a pattern of chars but not an individual char from that pattern

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to create a regex that will do the following

Match the String if:

- The String is between 4-35 chars
- The String must contain the `$` as the last char in the String
- The String does not contain any `$` anywhere else unless the dollar sign is wrapped within a bracket, i.e. `[$]`

I currently have the following regex: `[^\$]{3,34}\$$`

You can see the example [here](https://regex101.com/r/S3iTdT/2)

This catches not allowing `$` except at the end, however I still need to allow the dollar sign if it is wrapped within brackets `[$]`. How can I add a way to "allow" the `[$]`?

Some **Positive** examples:

- ABCD$
- ABC[$]D$
- [$]ABCDEFG$
- !@#%^&*[$]^%$

Some **Negative** examples:

- AB$CD
- ABCD
- $$ABCD$
- AB$[$]CD$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{4,35}$)(?:\[\$]|[^$])*\$$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7w69Cu/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (can be omitted if the pattern is used with `matches()`)
- `(?=.{4,35}$)`  - a positive lookahead requiring 4 to 35 chars in the string
- `(?:\[\$]|[^$])*` - 0+ `[$]` substrings or any chars other than `$`
- `\$` - a literal `$`
- `$` - end of string (may be omitted if used with `matches()`).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/EaZ0zX):

```
String lines[]  = {"ABCD$","ABC[$]D$","[$]ABCDEFG$","!@#%^&*[$]^%$","AB$CD","ABCD","$$ABCD$","AB$[$]CD$"};
String pat = "(?=.{4,35}$)(?:\\[\\$]|[^$])*\\$";
for(String line : lines)
{
    System.out.println(line + ": " + line.matches(pat));
}
```

Result:

```
ABCD$: true
ABC[$]D$: true
[$]ABCDEFG$: true
!@#%^&*[$]^%$: true
AB$CD: false
ABCD: false
$$ABCD$: false
AB$[$]CD$: false
```